# insert "\footnote{}" in my page footer

Tags: footnotes, footer

I have a problem with positioning a footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}

\title{test footnote}
\author{Tony}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\begin{flushleft}
test\footnote{voir plus bas}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to put the footnote inside my footer, like I could write

```
\fancyfoot[L]{...}
```

I tried :

```
\fancyfoot[L]{\tiny\insert\footins}
```

Unfortunately, this command doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can't really use footnote put the text in a page foot in a custom page style and use `\thispagestyle`

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

`\myfootnote` uses the same counter and `\footnotemark` as `\footnote`, which still functions normally.  It does not check if the last footnote is actually on the page, nor if the note will fit the bottom margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}

\title{test footnote}
\author{Tony}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\newsavebox{\myfootins}

\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{\footnotemark\myfootnotetext{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfootnotetext}[1]{\setbox\myfootins=\vbox{%
  \unvbox\myfootins
  \normalfont\footnotesize
  \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
  \splittopskip\footnotesep
  \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM% ???
  \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
  \makebox[1.8em][r]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnote}}#1}%
}
\makeatother

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\ifvoid\myfootins\else
  \setlength{\dimen1}%
    {\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight+\footskip+\ht\myfootins-\ht\strutbox}%
  \ifodd\value{page}\relax
    \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin}%
  \else
    \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr 1in+\evensidemargin}%
  \fi
  \put(\dimen0,-\dimen1){\box\myfootins}%
\fi}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage
\section{Introduction}

test\myfootnote{voir plus bas}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! My document looks greater by now !